# Expressions such as “la crème de la crème” and others

Tags: expressions, ressources

I am looking for a list of expressions meaning "the best of" such as "la crème de la crème". I would like some serious and funny ones, anyone has some in mind? or a reference for that (I will be surprised that there is no such lists on the internet but did not find one)?

Comment: Do you want only idoms like "X de X", where X is "crème", or "élite", etc... ? or anything that means the same thing ?

Comment: @Random Anything that means the same thing.

Comment: Does "c'est la cerise sur le gâteau" fits ?

Comment: You could try "c'est le pied" - informal - literally "the foot".

Comment: @Kii "La cerise sur le gâteau" is something that comes on top of the rest, not necessarily something excellent.

Comment: @Vérace "C'est le pied" is far from being similar, alluding to some extreme pleasure, not to excellence.

Comment: @Did For me, extreme pleasure is excellent :-) The OP said "I would like some serious and funny ones" - I believe that my humble contribution fits their requirement.

Comment: @Vérace No. Sorry.

Comment: Note that the answer marked correct includes "le fromage" - assez similaire, non?

Comment: @Vérace Indeed some items in the accepted answer are rather surprising, to say the least. The OP might be copying some source, which it would be good to know. The other upvoted answer seems much more in tune with common usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some options-

Serious:

- nec plus ultra
- summum (de xxx)
- apogée
- fleuron
- comble
- rien de mieux ("il n'y a rien de mieux")
- le fin du fin

Funny or slang:

- le max
- le pompon ("c'est le pompon")
- la haute
- le bout du bout ("c'est le bout du bout")
- le top niveau
- voir Naples et mourir (with a !)
- la bête
- extra
- la mer et les étoiles
- le fromage

Some of these expressions may not always be understood in that meaning, depending upon the audience and the context.

Comment: "Apogée"? Jamais lu ou entendu "la crème de la crème" utilisé dans ce sens.

Comment: In the context of the OP's question. Example:"Il représente l'apogée de la classe criminelle de son époque", i.e. "the best of" see OP's exact formulation above.  Btw - this example is, of course, somewhat sardonic:-)

Comment: Where is the example coming from?

Comment: L'apothéose maybe? Or la culmination? Le sommet? Le pic? Le zenith? Le climax? L'acmé? L'essence même? Il y en tellement...

Comment: Sorry but it seems I must be more explicit here: "l'apogée" is never used to mean "la crème de la crème". Larousse's online dictionary defines "apogée" as "Point de l'orbite d'un corps céleste où la distance de ce corps à la Terre est maximale" and provides the expression "Être à l'apogée de sa carrière". Both clearly indicate that one is talking about the moment when the position in a given trajectory, possibly taken in a figurative sense, is maximal, but certainly not an individual taken from a collection and being optimal with respect to some criterium. ...

Comment: ... Likewise, to suggest "climax" or "acmé" or "zénith" is frankly misleading. In the answer above, "comble" is also not acceptable (and please do not make me comment the "Slang" part...). As I said in another comment, these dubious lists seem to be copied from some source, rather blindly I must say, but anyway, to know the source would be a plus.

Comment: The OP's post is not asking for a synonym to "la créme de la créme", but for expressions meaning "the best of," sorry you misunderstood his question. You ask for the source of the words: the list was not copied but created - so I am it:-)

Comment: *crème de la crème*

Answer (score 3):

> le gratin, l'élite d'un groupe de personnes.
>
> le premier choix de ce qu'il y a en magasin.
>
> le meilleur de tous.
>
> le dessus du panier, le top du top,

Answer (score 0):

If you only want expressions that litteraly only mean "The best element of any set", with no context for the set, here are my suggestions :
Keep in mind that you can basically look for synonyms of any of them for a list on the net. If you look for a particular connotation, please precise it as there are plenty of it !

Serious:
- Le maître / le leader
- La fine fleur
- Le fin du fin
- Le nec plus ultra 
- La quintessence
- Le meilleur, le primordial, l'essentiel, Le majeur

Slang or common :
- Le maestro
- Le top (du top, optional superlative)
- Le best
- Le Numéro Un / Le Number One / Le Numero Uno
- Le boss
- Le dieu